# Reshape Time series data for Conv2d Block

Tags: time-series, pandas, preprocessing, supervised-learning, numpy

I am modelling my time series data into a supervised learning problem for the input to a conv2d block in pytorch from this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/).

```
timesteps = 5

def to_supervised(train,n_input=timesteps,n_output=3):
    n_start = 0
    train_X , train_y = list(),list()
    for _ in range(len(train)):
        n_end = n_start + n_input
        n_out = n_end + n_output
        if n_out < train.shape[0]:
            x = train[n_start:n_end,:]
            y = train[n_end:n_out,0]
            train_X.append(x)
            train_y.append(y)
        n_start += 1
    return np.array(train_X),np.array(train_y)
```

How ever this code turns the input shape of (100,5) to (92,5,5). But what i am expecting it to make it a 4d array(batchsize, samples, Height, width) for the input of conv2d block.
So i have changed the code a little bit

```
timesteps = 5

def to_supervised(train,n_input=timesteps,n_output=3):
    n_start = 0
    train_X , train_y = list(),list()
    for _ in range(len(train)):
        n_end = n_start + n_input
        n_out = n_end + n_output
        if n_out < train.shape[0]:
            x = train[n_start:n_end,:,:] #Here
            y = train[n_end:n_out,:,0] # and here
            train_X.append(x)
            train_y.append(y)
        n_start += 1
    return np.array(train_X),np.array(train_y)
```

but it throws error `IndexError: too many indices for array`

I saw many guides for multivariate sequence but I don't understand how to apply this on this case

Comment: What does the `train` parameter look like in both cases? In the first version it seems to be 2-dimensions, while you are trying to retrieve 3-dimensions in the second version. This must be the reason for the error.

Comment: Ohh that's must be the case. But if it is possible to get 4d array like (4,23,5,5) by retrieving it from a 2d array (100,5)in the second version directly? Can you suggest some changes i need to make in the second version?

Comment: Here's a very similar question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932704/adding-dimensions-using-numpy-reshape
Ask pure code questions there, you will certainly get faster and better answers.